# Exposing IDs in a SaaS multi-tenant RESTful application

Tags: rest, database-design

We're constructing a multi-tenant application that stores user records in a common "user" TABLE. There is a tenantID for each user record to keep the data segregated.

We are exposing the API to the clients, and the API has actions on individual users.

```
GET /api/users/{id}
```

It doesn't seem right to expose our TABLE ids, which are an auto-generated PRIMARY key for all "users" in the table.  Is there a better practice, such as generating a unique hash for each user and making that the "ID" we expose for the client?  Or should we do a different kind of primary key for the table, like a hash or composite primary key that doesn't expose the incremental count? Or should we just create an incremented integer "ID" for each client's user?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There are some reasons to not use database auto-generated id as resource identifier:

- They are not user friendly : GET /api/users/5463287 vs /api/users/bob
- They may change across database update/restoration
- They are meaningless : arbitrary ids doesn't contains any semantics

A resource identifier in that case should be a unique alphanumeric with semantics (when that makes sense)